# How to extract json data from a post request in compojure?

Tags: clojure

I can easily extract params from a get request

```
(GET "/:id" [id] (encode {:foo "bar" :baz id})))
```

But I can't do the same for a post request. 
For example, I have such json

```
{"title": "some", "description": "another"}
```

This doesn't work:

```
(POST "/" [title description] (insert-post title description))
```

How can I do it for a post request? Should I use Liberator or another lib if it can facilitate the process?

Comment: Can I assume that the body of the post request is a single JSON document?

Answer (score 2):

You can access post data using the following binding:

```clj
(POST "/" {:keys [params]}
  (insert-post params))
```

or, if you want your json data to be destructured

```clj
(POST "/" {:keys [params]}
  (let [{:keys [title description]} params]
    (insert-post title description)))
```

Just don't forget to add an appropriate ring middleware to parse your json body, e.g. [`wrap-json-params` from `ring-json` module](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-json), because default [`wrap-params` middleware](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.middleware.params.html#var-wrap-params) included in [all compojure build-in handlers](http://weavejester.github.io/compojure/compojure.handler.html) parses only urlencoded data:

```clj
(def app
  (-> (handler/site your-routes)
      wrap-json-params))
```

Comment: Leonid, I've done that you said and still have a problem:  Unable to resolve symbol: wrap-json-params in this context.  I am using [ring.middleware.json     :only  [wrap-json-params] and this code:
(def app
  (-> (handler/site routes)
      wrap-json-params))

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in data. My post request contained data in body parameter (not in query path). I just need to read the chain: request, and then body. I also was needed to decode body from InputStream to the string and I used a very convenient function called slurp.

Also I am using liberator now and that's why my solution looks like (pay attention to application/json):

```
(defroutes app
  (ANY "/posts" []
    (resource
      :allowed-methods [:post :get]
      :available-media-types ["text/html" "application/json"]
      :handle-ok (fn [ctx](...omitted))
      :post! (fn [ctx] (println (-> ctx :request :body slurp decode)))
      ...))
```

And this solved the problem
(-> ctx :request :body slurp decode)